# How To Combine These Specific Multiple .htaccess Rewrite Redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I cannot find a way to combine these 3 lines into one line, as a catch all for the url parameter "displayby".

The following 3 lines work, if the value is either price, date or menu_order but does anyone know how to write a directive that will catch all three of them, or even more? - as in any variable?

On the site different pages have example displayby=price, so as the examples work before, they need to redirect to the original URL - i.e.

www.example.com/category/kits/?displayby=price

to

www.example.com/category/kits/

Here is the code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^displayby=price$
RewriteRule ^category/kits/$ https://www.example.com/category/kits/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ displayby=date$
RewriteRule ^category/kits/$ https://www.example.com/category/kits/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ displayby=menu_order$
RewriteRule ^category/kits/$ https://www.example.com/category/kits/? [L,R=301]
```

The above works perfectly, but how can I combine these into one directive that will catch all?

I do thank you in advance for your assistance.

**Update**

Better yet, if any URL that has a URL paramter of that type "displayby=*" can it be redirected to the URL it's attached to. Specifically for displayby.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^displayby=(.*?)$
RewriteRule ^category/kits/$ https://www.example.com/category/kits/? [L,R=301]
```

`(.*?)` should regex match any value here without being too greedy

Comment: Hi JKirchartz, and thank you for your response. My apologies for the delay in responding. I replaced my blocks of code above with yours and it didn't work. Am I supposed to add only that line or add a RewriteCond as well?

Comment: crc, keep your first RewriteRule & Cond, delete the rest, and use this in place of your first RewriteCond

Comment: Hi again JKirchartz; ok just to be clear, if I keep that RewriteRule, than it will only apply to the kits category correct? I'm wondering what the code will be if the displayby was attached to any URL. My apologies for the misunderstanding if there is one. Thank you again.

Comment: @crc check out this tool to test your htaccess file: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ & this article that (I think) explains exactly what you're trying to do: https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-rewriterule-and-query-string/